# paypal sandbox refund transaction not showing up

Tags: .net, api, soap, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I am trying to integrate paypal refund into our web application. We are using a really old version of the classic API (v 2.3) . It is working for authorization and capture payment. here are some details

1. paypal classic API NPV
2. have a sandbox account for testing
3. authorization and capture payment goes through fie with username, password and signature.

On the sandbox account, the payment status is always pending and never moves to complete.
When i try to use full or partial refund, I do ACK = success and with a corelation id. but nothing shows up on the sanbox portal. here's the code that i use to do the refund.

```
 'build the request string to process one paypal refund
                        pp = "&METHOD=RefundTransaction"
                        pp = pp & "&TRANSACTIONID=" & transactionId
                        pp = pp & "&REFUNDTYPE=PARTIAL"
                        pp = pp & "&AMT=" & Math.Round(amount, 2)
                        pp = pp & "&CURRENCYCODE=USD"
                        pp = pp & "&NOTE=Refund " & refundRow("Store") & "Order " & refundRow("OrderNo").ToString
```

i get a response, and it is something like this.

Response Content:

```
BUILD 13443xxx
VERSION 2.3
ACK Success
TIMESTAMP 2014-10-23T16:44:36Z
CORELATIONID exxxx7e2dxxxx
```

I always get success but nothing shows up when i logon to sandbox portal.

I test couple of refunds on the live site as well. It has exactly the same issue.

Any inputs?

Partial Refund Request and Response

### Request

```
<soapenv:Envelope  xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"  xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" >
  <soapenv:Header>
    <ns:RequesterCredentials>
      <ebl:Credentials>
        <ebl:Username>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ebl:Username>
        <ebl:Password>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ebl:Password>
        <ebl:Signature>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ebl:Signature>
      </ebl:Credentials>
    </ns:RequesterCredentials>
  </soapenv:Header>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:RefundTransactionReq>
      <ns:RefundTransactionRequest>
        <ns:TransactionID>O-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</ns:TransactionID>
        <ns:RefundType>Partial</ns:RefundType>
        <ns:Amount currencyID="USD">7</ns:Amount>
        <ebl:Version>94.0</ebl:Version>
      </ns:RefundTransactionRequest>
    </ns:RefundTransactionReq>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

### Response

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:SOAP-ENC="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:cc="urn:ebay:apis:CoreComponentTypes" xmlns:wsu="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/utility" xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.0:assertion" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns:wsse="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xmlns:ed="urn:ebay:apis:EnhancedDataTypes" xmlns:ebl="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xmlns:ns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <Security xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/12/secext" xsi:type="wsse:SecurityType">
    </Security>
    <RequesterCredentials xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI" xsi:type="ebl:CustomSecurityHeaderType">
      <Credentials xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:UserIdPasswordType">
        <Username xsi:type="xs:string">
        </Username>
        <Password xsi:type="xs:string">
        </Password>
        <Signature xsi:type="xs:string">
        </Signature>
        <Subject xsi:type="xs:string">
        </Subject>
      </Credentials>
    </RequesterCredentials>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body id="_0">
    <RefundTransactionResponse xmlns="urn:ebay:api:PayPalAPI">
      <Timestamp xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">2014-10-25T06:07:08Z</Timestamp>
      <Ack xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">Success</Ack>
      <CorrelationID xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">45xxxxxxxxxxx</CorrelationID>
      <Version xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">94.0</Version>
      <Build xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents">1xxxxx4</Build>
      <RefundTransactionID>
      </RefundTransactionID>
      <TotalRefundedAmount xsi:type="cc:BasicAmountType" currencyID="USD">-7.00</TotalRefundedAmount>
      <RefundInfo xmlns="urn:ebay:apis:eBLBaseComponents" xsi:type="ebl:RefundInfoType">
        <RefundStatus xsi:type="ebl:PaymentStatusCodeType">None</RefundStatus>
        <PendingReason xsi:type="ebl:PendingStatusCodeType">none</PendingReason>
      </RefundInfo>
    </RefundTransactionResponse>
  </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Comment: Something is off.  If the payment is always pending and never completes then you wouldn't get a successful response on the refund request.  Can you post a sample of the original payment request and response, and then also a sample of the refund request and response?  Not the code generating it, but the actual raw API request/response.

Comment: let me correct that .. sometimes the payment does go to complete status... unfortunetely i do have the request and response for original payment Authirization and capture. I have updated my post with request and response data for partial refund ..

Answer (score 0):

Ok I was able to resolve this issue with the help of PayPal technical support team.

Basically there are 2 types of transaction ids. One that we get when we call DoAuthorize and another that we get when we call DoCapture. All the refunds is possible with the latter (DoCapture) transaction Id.

help link:
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-orderAuthPayment-curl-etc/

Though I have the answer I am not particularly happy with the response that we get when we call the RefundTransaction API with transaction Id from DoAuthorize call. I returns SUCCESS ????? and also with a co-relation id. but nothing shows up in the account.

PayPal tech team, if you ever stumble upon this post, them please either correct the problem or explain why does it make sense.